# Parsing a external JsonFile

Tags: javascript, json

Hey guys i'am trying to parse the following json file: http://osthessen-news.de/json2.php

For achieving this i am using the following javascript:

UPDATE:

```
<body>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>



        var url = 'http://osthessen-news.de/json2.php';

        alert("ASDFFD");

        $(document).ready(function(){
                          var url = "http://osthessen-news.de/json2.php";
                          $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                                    var output="<ul>";
                                    for (var i in data.news) {
                                    output+="<li>" + data.news[i].id + " " + data.news[i].Ueberschrift +"</li>";
                                    }

                                    output+="</ul>";
                                    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
                                    });
                          });          

    </script>
</body>
```

Found on this Website: http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Iam new to json in javascript. And i tried different approaches too. So can anybody tell me what im doing wrong? Thx in advance :)

Comment: `Ueberschrift` instead of `ueberschrift`. keys are case sensitive

Comment: You have `data.users[i]` instead of `data.news[i]` near `ueberschrift`. I don't think that's right.

Comment: what is the url you are calling this file from?

Comment: I updated the code as recommended but its still not working.

Comment: iam calling it from localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular for loop instead of the for..in syntax.  `For..in` is mostly used for iterating the properties of an object, while the regular for syntax is more appropriate for arrays.  Since news is an array, the regular syntax is most appropriate.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
    output+="<li>" + data.news[i].id + " " + data.news[i].ueberschrift +"</li>";
}
```

Also, try wrapping all this in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = "http://osthessen-news.de/json2.php"; 
 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.news) {
        output+="<li>" + data.news[i].id + " " + data.news[i].ueberschrift +"</li>";
    }

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular each loop instead of the for..in syntax.

```
jQuery.each(data.news, function(j, val) {
    output+="<li>" + val.id + " " + val.ueberschrift +"</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting an error on Chrome (XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://osthessen-news.de/json2.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.)

You can't load files via AJAX from different domains.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: yes.. I a getting the same error. what is the solution ??  I have also tried .ajax with JSONP as datatype... Not working....

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and the object doesn't have `.ueberschrift`, it has `.Ueberschrift` which is important (case sentivity).

also, this is jquery, so (warning: this is style nitpicking on my part):

`for (var i in data.news)`

should be

`$(data.news).each( ...`

and

`document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;`

should be

`$('#placeholder').html(output);`